# Infragistics columnfilter

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

In my application i have used WebDataGrid Infragistics control. I have total 5 columns(Status,CandidateName,WorkOrderId,VenderName,Rate) in this grid. I needed to apply filter on 2 columns only i.e; Status and CandidateName.  I have explicitly write code to set filter only in 2 columns. Below is my code. But, the problem is, Filter is applying on all the 5 columns regardless of setting the filter explicitly.

```
  <ColumnFilters>
                        <ig:ColumnFilter ColumnKey="Status">
                                <ConditionWrapper>
                                    <ig:RuleTextNode Rule="Contains" />
                                </ConditionWrapper>
                         </ig:ColumnFilter>
                         <ig:ColumnFilter ColumnKey="CandidateName">
                                <ConditionWrapper>
                                    <ig:RuleTextNode Rule="Contains" />
                                </ConditionWrapper>                 
                          </ig:ColumnFilter>
 </ColumnFilters>
```

Please any one can tell me how to apply filter only on specific columns defined explicitly.

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable the other columns by setting Enabled=false as follows:

```
<Behaviors>
    <ig:Filtering>
        <ColumnSettings>
            <ig:ColumnFilteringSetting ColumnKey="WorkOrderId" Enabled="false" />
            <ig:ColumnFilteringSetting ColumnKey="VenderName" Enabled="false" />
            <ig:ColumnFilteringSetting ColumnKey="Rate" Enabled="false" />
        </ColumnSettings>
    </ig:Filtering>
</Behaviors>
```